# POS tagger in SharpNLP

Tags: c#, nlp, pos-tagger

I am using SharpNLP for my POS tagging:

```
EnglishMaximumEntropyPosTagger posTagger =
  new EnglishMaximumEntropyPosTagger(mModelPath);
            String tagSentence = posTagger.TagSentence(question);
```

I only have 3 tags. How can I load a set of Penn treebank or some other tagging tree banks to use?

Thanks

:)

Answer (score 0):

Download the model files from http://www.codeplex.com/sharpnlp, and use `mModelPath` to point to the models you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

For POS Tagging, be sure to initialize the PosTagger object not just with the nbin file, but also with the tagdict file.

```
mPosTagger = new OpenNLP.Tools.PosTagger.EnglishMaximumEntropyPosTagger(mModelPath + "EnglishPOS.nbin", mModelPath + @"\Parser\tagdict");
```